# IE11 some selects are treated as tapable on desktop

Tags: web, internet-explorer-11

We are using react-day-picker with http://react-day-picker.js.org/examples/elements-year-navigation.

Even on this page in IE11 you can see "IE prevents navigation" when trying to switch months / years.

If this is used as "input" version (modal, popover..) selects are treated like "tapable". They open on double click with mouse but on first "tap" with touchable screen.

It is possible to switch off it?

Comment: I try to make a test on that page using Ie 11 in sandbox and also on that same example page but it works correctly on my side. I did not find that IE prevents any navigation when trying to switch months or years. Here is my testing result. https://i.postimg.cc/QtsDSzPN/84.gif You can try to post your own code with your testing results. We will try to check for the issue. If we talk about disabling the tap than it is more related with React.JS and you can try to contact their support to know if there is any way to do it.

Comment: I will try to provide an example later today, unfortunately, code sandbox does not work in IE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've already fixed that, it was problem with focus handling in inputs.